# Replacing intercept with dummy variables in ARIMAX models in R

Tags: r, time-series, intercept

I am attempting to fit an ARIMAX model to daily consumption data in R. When I perform an OLS regression with `lm()` I am able to include a dummy variable for each unit and remove the constant term (intercept) to avoid less then full rank matrices.

```
lm1 <- lm(y ~ -1 + x1 + x2 + x3, data = dat)
```

I have not found a way to do this with `arima()` which forces me to use the constant term and exclude one of the dummy variables.

```
with(dat, arima(y, xreg = cbind(x1, x2))
```

Is there a specific reason why `arima()` doesn't allow this and is there a way to bypass?

Comment: See the documentation for the argument `include.mean` in `?arima`, it seems you want the following: `arima(y, xreg = cbind(x1, x2), include.mean=FALSE)`.

Comment: @javiacalle Works perfectly. I am ashamed I missed this in the documentation. Would you like to change from comment to answer so I can mark it appropriately?

Comment: Nice to see it worked. This post may be marked as off-topic by moderators since it turned out to be related to software usage. If this post is migrated to stackoverflow I will consider posting the comment as an answer.

Comment: @javiacalle Thank you. I'm not proficient enough in StackExchange to know if I personally am supposed to migrate or the moderators will do so automatically. Although I missed the appropriate documentation I searched diligently on Stack Overflow and Cross Validated (and google) and did not find an answer. Keeping this question up would spare others from the same.

Comment: Note that `arima` with exogenous regressors will fit a regression with ARMA errors, not an ARIMAX model. See [here](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/) for an explanation.

Comment: @RichardHardy Thank you sir. Good to learn new things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the documentation for the argument `include.mean` in `?arima`, it seems you want the following: `arima(y, xreg = cbind(x1, x2), include.mean=FALSE)`.

Be also aware of the definition of the model fitted by ARIMA as pointed by @RichardHardy.